# Why is there a Foreign Key conflict

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the main table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Control_cReport](
    [ReportKey] [int] IDENTITY(10000,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReportTechKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessKey] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Control_cReport] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ReportKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Control_cReport]  WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Control_cReport_cReportTech] FOREIGN KEY([ReportTechKey])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Control_cReportTech] ([ReportTechKey])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Control_cReport] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Control_cReport_cReportTech]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Control_cReport] ADD  DEFAULT ((12)) FOR [ProcessKey]
GO
```

Here is the secondary table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Control_cReportTech](
    [ReportTechKey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReportTechDescription] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__Control_cReportTech] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ReportTechKey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I've then added to the secondary table:

```
INSERT INTO [WHAnalysis].[dbo].Control_cReportTech  
VALUES  
    (1,'Excel Macros'),
    (2,'VB Script'),
    (3,'PDF'),
    (4,'Batch')
```

Now I'm attempting to `INSERT` some data from an old table into the main table via this:

```
INSERT INTO [WHAnalysis].[dbo].[Control_cReport]
SELECT
    [ProcessKey] = 12,
    [ReportTechKey] = 1
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.Controltb_ReportingScheduler_jq
```

I get this error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Control_cReport_cReportTech". The
>   conflict occurred in database "WHAnalysis", table
>   "dbo.Control_cReportTech", column 'ReportTechKey'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is because you are attempting to `INSERT` a value in the `ProcessKey` field, that does not exist in the `Control_cReportTech` table.

I would alter the `INSERT` statement to specify the fields that you are trying to `INSERT` into:

```
INSERT INTO [Control_cReport] (ProcessKey, ReportTechKey)
SELECT 12 as ProcessKey, 1 as ReportTechKey;
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.Controltb_ReportingScheduler_jq;
```

See [SQL Fiddle With Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eaea1/7)

Use the above query instead of your current query because when the columns are not specified, it attempts to insert the values in the order of the table structure.  So it is attempting to insert a value of `12` into the `ReportTechKey` column which violates the Foreign Key.

You are always much better off specifying the order of the columns that you are inserting data into.

Comment: ...I thought `[ProcessKey] = 12` was equivalent to `12 as ProcessKey` ?!

Comment: @whytheq the difference is that I am specifying the columns in the `INSERT` -- `INSERT INTO [Control_cReport] (ProcessKey, ReportTechKey)`, you are not so it doesn't know where to place the values

Comment: ahhh -nice one; just putting the columns in the correct order in the `SELECT` clause works but if I use your method in the future then the code is much more defensive as it avoids problems with the schema changing

Comment: @whytheq yes, that is why it is much better to specify the columns in the `INSERT` and `SELECT`, keep them in the same order otherwise it will not know what field to insert the value.